# how to render a welcome page in page--front.tpl.php

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a template `page--front.tpl.php`. 
It contains all different stuffs and a welcome message, wrapped in a div container. Since, I want it to be editable, I created a new basic page called 'Welcome message'. It opens in a separate node 'welcome-message'.

Now I want this to be rendered in `page--front.tpl.php` in given div container. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have any other content on the front page/

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to use a block to store your welcome message instead? Using an entire new node seems like overkill to me

Answer (score -1):

Login as admin to the site, visit "`admin/config/system/site-information`" , scroll down to find setting for for front page and then form "Default front page" set the node relative path to be used as default front page that looks like "`welcome-message`" in your case.

with the above process you have informed drupal to use the node you have created as front page.

Now remove the hard-coded page front template you have created before as "`page--front.tpl.php`" because it will be used over the node till its present there.

clear your caches.

Comment: OP needs to put the content in div container.

Comment: @Bala "Since, I want it to be editable, I created a new basic page called 'Welcome message" , anyway node body will be in a container,also I do not consider it to be overkill instead will be easy to edit and scale further